# Meson build - rust - lib cdylib

Tags: rust, shared-libraries, meson-build

How to configure a meson build file to build a libray in rust with option crate_type=["cdylib"] ?

Actually, my Cargo.toml :

```
[lib]
name = "my_lib"
path = "my_op.rs"
crate_type=["cdylib"]
```

Equivalent in meson.build:

```
library(
    'my_lib',
    ['my_op.rs', ],
    install : true,
)
```

Comment: https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-42-0.html#allow-crate-type-configuration-for-rust-compiler

Comment: OK, at first read, https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-42-0.html#allow-crate-type-configuration-for-rust-compiler seem to be the right answer of my question. After try this:
library(
    'my_lib',
    ['my_op.rs', ],
    rust_crate_type : 'cdylib',
    install : true,
)
Compilation, is OK. But on execution, I have same linking trouble than without this ...
I am still looking for a solution with google ...

Comment: OK, now I can used my library build with meson, but I have to add in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib , not perfect, but operational.